# How to pause video recording in ios application (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcam

Using AVCam I'm abel to start and stop video recording.
This method to start recording:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections;
```

and to stop recording :

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error;
```

My question is how can I pause recording? looking into the AVFoundation I can found a pause method which is :

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didPauseRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
```

but I can't find a way to make it function.
I searched a lot but nothing seemed to solve my problem, so please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about **changing** the method
From AVCam
to **CameraEngine**?

```
    #import "CameraEngine.h"


- (void) startPreview
{
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* preview = [[CameraEngine engine] getPreviewLayer];
    [preview removeFromSuperlayer];
    preview.frame = self.cameraView.bounds;
    [[preview connection] setVideoOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

    [self.cameraView.layer addSublayer:preview];
}



    - (IBAction)startRecording:(id)sender
    {
        [[CameraEngine engine] startCapture];
    }

    - (IBAction)pauseRecording:(id)sender
    {
        [[CameraEngine engine] pauseCapture];
    }

    - (IBAction)stopRecording:(id)sender
    {
        [[CameraEngine engine] stopCapture];
    }
    - (IBAction)resumeRecording:(id)sender
    {
        [[CameraEngine engine] resumeCapture];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Solved it using [link](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision). 
I'll try your suggestion another time.